# Why do we use 'take', and what does it mean in 'does he take sugar'?

Tags: idioms

The verb 'take' is used in the context of personal habits such as *Do you take sugar?*; *What size shoes do you take?*, *Do you take the Guardian/New York Times?*, even *At what time do you take dinner?*, or *I need to take a bath/nap/look at something*.

**Why, exactly are we using 'take', in these instances?**

Comment: You forgot *And now I must take my leave of you*. That one doesn't work at all with ***have*** - but most others do, and I think increasingly people prefer to avoid what can sound like a rather dated usage in many contexts.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers Yes *take my leave* is a good one. But the only ones of mine for which in Britain I hear people using *have* is for bath and dinner. I *take* size 10 shoes, and I've always *taken* size 10.

Comment: Putting aside the ones that ***have** size 10 feet*, I suspect an increasing proportion of the remainder *wear* (or maybe *fit*) size 10s, rather than take them. I dunno. I just think *Do you take sugar?* sounds (very slightly) formal/starchy/dated. As does taking a newspaper, a nap, or lunch(eon :)

Comment: it's an ingenious question.

Comment: You also *take* time off work, *take photos*, *take a break* and [*After dinner I take tea, and then I take a walk*](https://books.google.it/books?id=MskDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA235&dq=%22take+a+walk%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI6NHG2O3rxwIVirwUCh0H2wRX#v=onepage&q=%22take%20a%20walk%22&f=false). Is "What size shoe do you take" a habit?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Probably not. The difference between it and the others is that we do not have a choice in the matter. So you have established that*take* applies to choices that are forced upon us. Good point. Can you think of any others?  We do *take a breath* , a rather essential practice.

Answer (score 4):

I think it has to do with the semantic evolution that this  term has experienced  from Old English.

> - OED calls take ***"one of the elemental words of the language;***" take up alone has 55 varieties of meaning in that dictionary's 2nd print edition. Basic sense is "to lay hold of," ***which evolved to "accept, receive" (as in take my advice) c. 1200;*** "absorb" (take a punch) c. 1200; "choose, select" (take the high road) late 13c.; "to make, obtain" (take a shower) late 14c.; "to become affected by" (take sick) c. 1300.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=take)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's *"take"*; as in the sense of *"accept"* and *"receive"*.

---

Consider a hypothetical scenario in which you are presented with some arbitrary item. For instance, a mail courier delivers you a suspicious package. You can either *"accept" & "receive"* the suspicious package ***or*** you can opt to *"reject" & "refuse"* it.
That is to say: You can either *"take"* it ***or*** you can *"leave"* it.

---

Of course, it doesn't necessarily have to be a mail courier and a suspicious package. It could be a friend with a gift for your birthday.. It could be a perfect stranger, offering his personal opinion.. It could be a shoe salesman enquiring about your size, or an acquaintance offering you some sugar for your coffee.

Answer (score 1):

This usage always implies a choice.  It's saying: 'When *given* the usual range of options, which do you habitually *take*?'  In the relevant situations (serving tea, buying shoes, selecting a newspaper) the options are commonly understood, and taken(!) as read.

See also [**take your pick**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+your+pick) - *"to choose what you want."*

Answer (score 0):

We use take because the subject is actively involved.  If they weren't, we'd use [get](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-take-and-vs-get/).